# What is the best and effective way to document asp.net web system

Tags: asp.net, documentation, comments

I have developed an `ASP.Net` web system for about 4.5 years with `.Net Framework 2`, `DataSets` and `Ajax`. I want to document the code in a way that a new developer can start reading the documentation so that he can work effectively without asking me what to do ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of documenting .NET code is using [XML Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx). This should be sufficient for most purposes. Of course if you wrote large methods it might help to put comments in the method bodies at strategic points.